Kafka Mapped Types - Consumer failing during application run due to Class definition not found
I know similar questions have been already asked and I have tried all of those and yet I could not resolve it.
Please find link below to the references tried:

How to configure Kafka type mapping using spring boot, maven build success but contain errors?
How to map types using properties file in Kafka_

Please find below the spring settings in producer yaml ------
  kafka:
producer:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  key-serializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringSerializer
  value-serializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonSerializer

Please find below the spring settings in producer properties ------
spring.kafka.producer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=mail:com.upcoming.vice.model.ItemMail

Please find below the spring settings in consumer yaml ------
  kafka:
consumer:
  bootstrap-servers: localhost:9092
  group-id: mail-notifications
  auto-offset-reset: earliest
  enable-auto-commit: false
  key-deserializer: org.apache.kafka.common.serialization.StringDeserializer
  value-deserializer: org.springframework.kafka.support.serializer.JsonDeserializer

Please find below the spring settings in consumer properties ------
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.type.mapping=mail:com.schedule.notify.model.ItemMail
spring.kafka.consumer.properties.spring.json.trusted.packages=*

Please find below the class definition -------
public class ItemMail implements Serializable {
public String to;
public String subject;
public String body;
}

Please find below the kafkalistener config class in consumer ----------------
@Configuration
@KafkaListener(topics = "itemSaved")
public class KafkaConsumerConfig {
@KafkaHandler
public void handleItemMail(ItemMail mail) {
    System.out.println("Received mail: " + mail);
}
}

The error that I am getting --------
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JavaType
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.BuiltinClassLoader.loadClass(BuiltinClassLoader.java:641) ~[na:na]
at java.base/jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoaders.java:188) ~[na:na]
at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:526) ~[na:na]
... 42 common frames omitted


It seems you don't have a dependency to Jackson library. Please share your pom.xml

The error indeed has nothing to do with mapping or configuration: you just don't have a com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind dependency in your project.

The error points to missing of the com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind
dependency. Adding this dependency resolved the issue and message  is flowing from producer to consumer.
The issue is pointed out by Mar-z and Artem Bilan in comments.
